# Got an error with react-native-navigation with upgraded react-native 0.59 to 0.61

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

Got a problem with react-native-navigation on upgrade react59 to react61 please help me. 
check to attach image.[image]

Comment: Have you added `missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative60"` to your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

Please add missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative60" in android/app/build.gradle file.

```
 android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourproject"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative60"// add this line
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```